# Prove that for any finite k = 1, 2, 3 … PCPk is decidable

Tags: complexity-theory, mathematical-foundations

Let PCPk be a version of PCP where we can use at most k copies of each domino to create correspondences. Prove that for any finite k = 1, 2, 3 … PCPk is decidable.

I know this kind of PCP is called bounded PCP which is decidable. Does anyone know how to prove the decidability?

Comment: Is PCP for "probabilistically checkable proof" or the class or ? Can you define domino ?

Comment: You should be able to prove it by induction and with the Rice theorem.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot In this question it probably refers to the [Post correspondence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem).

Comment: If you can use each tile only a bounded number of times, then there are only a finite number of combinations to consider.